# Terminfo does not export the up arrow resource

Tags: shell, tramp, terminfo

When I use `TRAMP` and a remote shell, `terminfo` doesn't export the `kcuu1` (up arrow) resource. How can I get Emacs to provide this?

Comment: I almost feel like this is unrelated to `emacs`.

Answer (score 1):

The terminfo (and termcap) databases contain information about what escape sequences are used for various functions on a wide variety of terminals. These are keyed off of the name of the terminal you've specified in the TERM variable. I believe that shell and eshell use `dumb` while term and ansi-term use `eterm-color`. If you've change the value of the TERM variable (in your `~/.bashrc` file, for example) to some thing else, then it'll look up the wrong values to use. If TERM is correct then you need to check the contents of your terminfo database, and perhaps compile a new database to add the entry you want.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/22091145/324105